# why is this regular expression returning only one match?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

Here is my input:

> xxx999xxx888xxx777xxx666yyy
>
> xxx222xxx333xxx444xxx555yyy

This is the expression:

```
xxx.*xxx(?<matchString>(.(?!xxx.*xxx))*?)xxx.*yyy
```

It's returning **444**.

I'd like it to return both 444 and 777, but I can't get anywhere with this.

I have the *!* exclusion so that it matches only the innermost on the left side (which works great when I am searching for only one result, which is most of the time). However, I have a feeling that that is related to why it is skipping the first result in this instance. I'm not sure where to go from here.

I've been testing here:
http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx (with "SingleLine" and "Explicit Capture" enabled)

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You should also post your C# code.  I have a feeling you're overwriting results by accident.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I want to explain why your current solution doesn't work:

Since you've enabled `SingleLine` option, `.*` matches `999xxx888xxx777xxx666yyy\nxxx222xxx333`, the pattern in parenthesis matches `444`, and the rest of your Regex matches `xxx555yyy`.

So to match both `777` and `444` you can either disable `SingleLine` option or use something like this:

```
xxx\d+xxx\d+xxx(?<matchString>\d+)xxx\d+yyy
```