# why is this single-line regex not returning ALL matches?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I just asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923782/why-is-this-regular-expression-returning-only-one-match) to this one, and there was an excellent and accurate answer, but it turns out I now have a brand new problem. It turns out I have a *single line of relevant input*. I'm not sure how to ask this in an abstract way so I'll just jump right into my input:

(**EDITED to provide a better example**)

> bear999bear888bear777bear666fox---bear222bear333bear444bear555fox

(The items between the markers are not necessarily numeric)

This is the expression (**EDITED to match updated input example**):

```
bear.*bear(?<matchString>(.(?!bear.*bear))*?)bear.*fox
```

It's returning **444**. Is there a way that I can tweak this to return both **444 and 777**? It seems to be skipping over the first match and favoring only the latter. I have the *!* exclusion so that it matches only the innermost on the left side.

I've been testing here:
http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

**This works great when I break it into two lines and turn on multi-line. Why does it stop working when the input is on a single line?**

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can we say that `xxx[^xy]+yyy` is the closing delimiter here? See, in this particular example the `/([^x]+?)(?=xxx[^xy]+yyy)/g` pattern is quite enough...

Comment: @raina77ow - Thanks. I'm not sure I completely follow, but the delimiter is actually a group, rather than the specific character (in another example, it could be "ABC"). I'm a bit of a regex amateur, so I'm not quite sure how to translate that information onto your idea.

Comment: It doesn't matter how experienced (or not) with regex you're. ) The key point is ALWAYS defining two sets of data: one that should match (or be captured), and the other that shouldn't. Said this, can you show the string that won't be processed properly by the regex I've shown?

Comment: @raina77ow - For example, xxx999xxx888xxx777x000xxx666yyy---xxx222xxx333xxx444xxx555yyy, should return 777x000 and 444. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @raina77ow - I just updated the question, using "bear" and "fox" instead. I introduced some confusion by using the same repeated character in my example (I was trying to keep it readable but made it worse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (it does work in that regex tester you've linked in the question):

```
(?<=bear)(?:(?!bear).)*(?=bear(?:(?!bear).)*fox)
```

It reads like "let's match something that is preceded by `bear`, has no `bear` sequence within, and is followed by the `bear` - no `bear` - `fox` sequence".

The capturing groups are absent here; the whole match is what you need.

And yes, I just can't help wondering why should this be done with a single regex when it actually looks like a work for a tokenizer. ) For example, you can split your line by `'fox'` first, then split each part by `'bear'` - and take the one before the last one of each result.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `.*` is greedy. This will work:

```
xxx.*?xxx.*?xxx(?<matchString>.*?)xxx.*?yyy
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I need this to pick the innermost match, though. I don't think your example allows for a scenario such as xxx1xxx2xxx3xxx4xxx5xxx6yyy, in which case it will return "3" instead of the desired "5".

Comment: In what way is 5 the "innermost match"?

Comment: xxx.*?xxx.*?xxx will match on xxx1xxx2xxx, which is too far to the left, and result in a match of "3xxx4xxx5". I'm looking for the innermost match of the expression, which would match on xxx3xxx4xxx, which would result in "5".